# Conditional comparison with out of range values in C

Tags: c

How is this resolved by the compiler? Which implicit conversion is carried? Is it optimized maybe so that the conditional is always true? Will the following code be always safe? Or depends on the compiler.

```
#define MaxCfgDev 500

uint8 numdev;
.
.
.
if(numdev < MaxCfgDev)
.
.
.
```

I know maybe could not make sense at first sight to compare to a number beyond limits, but imagine that this `MaxCfgDev` is not defined so obviously but comes from another complex definition, maybe from other defines coming from external modules and this specific module only needs to check that `numdev` it is below some system level definitions or whatever.

Comment: It is always true. The compiler (a sane one) will even warn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `#define` performs a symbol substitution prior to the compiler being run.  So after substitution the condition will be exactly equivalent to:

```
if(numdev < 500)
```

It doesn't matter how "obvious" the definition of `MaxCfgDev` is.  If it evaluates to a compile time constant that is 256 or larger the condition will always be true, and the compiler may optimize out the test.

Answer (score 0):

Numdev is promoted to an `int` before comparison.